# Highcharts responsive ignored on first render

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have the following code for my legend, and a responsive rule to remove the legend for mobile.

The problem I'm seeing right now, is that the legend will always load with the chart initially. The responsive rule only seems to apply later (i.e. if I reload the page, the legend is there, if I click a link to another page, and then return, the legend is gone).

Is there a way to force the responsive check on load?

```
legend: {
    enabled: true,
    verticalAlign: 'top',
    align: 'right',
    floating: true,
    margin: 0,
    padding: 0,
    x: showConviction ? -50 : -46,
    y: 10
},
responsive: {
    rules: [
        {
            condition: {
                maxWidth: 400
            },
            chartOptions: {
                legend: {
                    enabled: false
                }
            }
        }
    ]
},
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check `chartWidth` when [load event](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.load) occurs and disable legend then.

HTML:

```
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

JS:

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {

  chart: {
    events: {
      load: function() {
        var chart = this,
          legend = chart.legend,
          chartWidth = chart.chartWidth;

        if (chartWidth < 400) {
          legend.update({
            enabled: false
          });
        }
      }
    }
  },

  plotOptions: {
    series: {
      label: {
        connectorAllowed: false
      },
      pointStart: 2010
    }
  },

  series: [{
    name: 'Installation',
    data: [43934, 52503, 57177, 69658, 97031, 119931, 137133, 154175]
  }, {
    name: 'Manufacturing',
    data: [24916, 24064, 29742, 29851, 32490, 30282, 38121, 40434]
  }],

  responsive: {
    rules: [{
      condition: {
        maxWidth: 400
      },
      chartOptions: {
        legend: {
          enabled: false
        }
      }
    }]
  }

});
```

Demo:
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/t1dswx4j/

Comment: Thanks Wojciech - this didn't work for me until I wrapped a setTimeout around the if statement. But I guess that is good enough!

Comment: Any idea why the responsive rules are not working? Even I have similar issue and for me its always taking responsive rules even though the rule is not met.